# Join table with current year and get prior year records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, join

Input

TableA

```
ID  YEAR    
101 2012
101 2013
101 2014
102 2012
102 2013
102 2014
```

TabeleB

```
ID  YEAR    AMOUNT
101 2011    2384
101 2012    2987
101 2013    3232
101 2014    3987
102 2011    2212
102 2012    2332
102 2013    2987
102 2014    3222
```

Output Table

```
ID  YEAR    AMOUNT  PREV YEAR AMOUNT
101 2012    2987    2384
101 2013    3232    2987
101 2014    3987    3232
102 2012    2332    2212
102 2013    2987    2332
102 2014    3222    2987
```

Problem Description: TableA will have selected years as base and tableB will have all the records but I need to join tableA and TableB to hook up the prior year data, please see output table. I have tried with self join but not able to get it.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Different years with the same id? Is Id your PK? I must confess that I've diffuculties to understand the scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is two joins:

```
select a.*, b.amount, bprev.amount
from a left join
     b
     on b.id = a.id and b.year = a.year left join
     b bprev
     on bprev.id = a.id and bprev.year = a.year - 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=84a7ced78bbfeb3622a6ca76fbeb2f8d) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: if I do left join , I am getting all records from tableB in outputtable, do we need to use join instead of Left join?

Comment: @Ashik . . . The `left join` keeps all tables in `a`, not `b` (see the fiddle).  You can use `join`, but it will filter rows if the year is the first year in the data or if a year is missing.

Answer (score 0):

If you all `ID`s have data for all years, you can just use window functions. This should be more efficient than a self-join, since it only scans `tableb` once:

```
select b.*
from tablea a
inner join (
    select b.*, lag(amount) over(partition by id order by year) prev_year_amount
    from tableb b
) a on a.id = b.id and a.year = b.year
```

Comment: Yes, that's correct but we don't have data for all years, might have breakage.